# Powershell pipelining: Convert System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController to PSObject

Tags: powershell

I always thought that Powershell pipelining is achieved via either name or type matching ( as described in [how pipelines work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6#how-pipelines-work)). That's ok for me. But how does Powershell achieves the following example:

```
> Get-Service "*win*" | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.DisplayName}
```

`Get-Service` returns an object of type `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`, ok. But `Foreach-Object` only accepts `PSObject` as `InputObject`:

```
> Get-Help ForEach-Object -Parameter inputobject

    -InputObject <PSObject>
     ...
     Accept pipeline input?       True (ByValue)
```

My question: How does Powershell convert any given object (because `Foreach-Object` can accept any input object) to a `PsObject`?

Thx

Comment: I would say that the documentation is the issue. If you do this: `Get-Service "*win*" | ForEach-Object{$_.GetType()}` you will see that they are still ServiceController objects inside the foreach-object.